# sql group by one column and then filter on one column and create new columns for different values

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, pivot

In an MS Access query, how can I group on one column, then using the max ID get specific values from the table. I know I can group and use max to get the max ID but then not sure how to get multiple max IDs.

If I have a table like this:

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| ID | Col1 | Col2  | Col3 |
+----+------+-------+------+
|  1 | a    | one   |  100 |
|  2 | a    | two   |  200 |
|  3 | a    | three |  300 |
|  4 | a    | four  |  400 |
|  5 | a    | five  |  500 |
|  6 | b    | one   |  600 |
|  7 | b    | two   |  700 |
|  8 | b    | three |  800 |
|  9 | b    | four  |  900 |
| 10 | b    | one   | 1000 |
| 11 | b    | three | 1100 |
| 12 | b    | six   | 1200 |
| 13 | c    | one   | 1300 |
| 14 | c    | two   | 1400 |
| 15 | c    | three | 1500 |
| 16 | c    | four  | 1600 |
| 17 | c    | six   | 1700 |
| 18 | c    | three | 1800 |
| 19 | c    | two   | 1900 |
| 20 | c    | one   | 2000 |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

And I want to get this:

```
+------+------+------+-------+
| Col1 | one  | two  | three |
+------+------+------+-------+
| a    |  100 |  200 |   300 |
| b    | 1000 |  700 |  1100 |
| c    | 2000 | 1900 |  1800 |
+------+------+------+-------+
```

When Col1 = b, and Col2 = one, ID = 6 and 10. Since 10 is larger it gets the value for that row which is 1000. Same for the rest of the table...

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

This returns the results you requested with your sample data in Access 2007.

```
SELECT
    sub.Col1,
    DLookup('Col3', 'YourTable', 'ID=' & sub.MaxOfID1) AS [one],
    DLookup('Col3', 'YourTable', 'ID=' & sub.MaxOfID2) AS [two],
    DLookup('Col3', 'YourTable', 'ID=' & sub.MaxOfID3) AS [three]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            y.Col1,
            Max(IIf(y.Col2='one', y.ID, 0)) AS MaxOfID1,
            Max(IIf(y.Col2='two', y.ID, 0)) AS MaxOfID2,
            Max(IIf(y.Col2='three', y.ID, 0)) AS MaxOfID3
        FROM YourTable AS y
        GROUP BY y.Col1
    ) AS sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not mentioned your RDBMS, the query below is supported on almost all RDBMS.

```
SELECT  Col1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = 'one' THEN Col3 END) one,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = 'two' THEN Col3 END) two,
        MAX(CASE WHEN Col2 = 'three' THEN Col3 END) three
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY Col1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2371/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╦═══════╗
║ COL1 ║ ONE  ║ TWO  ║ THREE ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╬═══════╣
║ a    ║  100 ║  200 ║   300 ║
║ b    ║ 1000 ║  700 ║  1100 ║
║ c    ║ 2000 ║ 1900 ║  1800 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: MS Access. And I made a mistake. The #s in Col3 are not always going to be larger so can't use max on that column. Gotta find the row ID with MAX and then get column value for that row...

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, 
    max(case col2 when 'one' then col3 else 0 end) as One,
    max(case col2 when 'two' then col3 else 0 end) as Two,
    max(case col2 when 'three' then col3 else 0 end) as three
from MyTable
group by col1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in MS-Access:

```
TRANSFORM Max(tbl.Col3) AS MaxDiCol3
SELECT tbl.Col1
FROM tbl
WHERE (((tbl.Col2)="one" Or (tbl.Col2)="two" Or (tbl.Col2)="three"))
GROUP BY tbl.Col1
PIVOT tbl.Col2;
```

If you need to get the maximum ID, instead of the maximum value, I would suggest you to use this instead:

```
TRANSFORM Max(tbl.ID) AS MaxDiCol3
SELECT tbl.Col1
FROM tbl
WHERE (((tbl.Col2)="one" Or (tbl.Col2)="two" Or (tbl.Col2)="three"))
GROUP BY tbl.Col1
PIVOT tbl.Col2;
```

And save it as a query, for example `Query1`. You can then get the actual values with this:

```
SELECT
  Query1.Col1,
  tbl.Col3 AS one,
  tbl_1.Col3 AS two,
  tbl_2.Col3 AS three
FROM
  ((Query1 LEFT JOIN tbl ON Query1.one = tbl.ID)
  LEFT JOIN tbl AS tbl_1 ON Query1.two = tbl_1.ID)
  LEFT JOIN tbl AS tbl_2 ON Query1.three = tbl_2.ID;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  t1. col1, 
  MAX(CASE WHEN t1.col2 = 'one' THEN t1.col3 END) AS 'one',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t1.col2 = 'two' THEN t1.col3 END) AS 'two',
  MAX(CASE WHEN t1.col2 = 'three' THEN t1.col3 END) AS 'three'
FROM tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT col1, MAX(ID) AS MAXID
  FROM tablename
  WHERE col2 IN('one', 'two', 'three')
  GROUP BY col1, col2
) AS t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.id = t2.maxid
GROUP BY t1.col1;
```

The `JOIN` with the subquery will give you only the values for the max id for each `col1` and `col2`.

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94cb2/8)

This will give you:

```
| COL1 |  ONE |  TWO | THREE |
------------------------------
|    a |  100 |  200 |   300 |
|    b | 1000 |  700 |  1100 |
|    c | 2000 | 1900 |  1800 |
```

---

**However:** if you are using a RDBMS that supports the window functions and the `PIVOT` table operator, like SQL Server, you can do this:

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1, col2
                      ORDER BY ID) AS RN
  FROM tablename
  WHERE col2 IN('one', 'two', 'three')
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM CTE
  WHERE RN <= 3
) AS t
PIVOT
(
  MAX(col3)
  FOR col2 IN([one], [two], [three])
) AS p;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/94cb2/9)

Comment: Yes. It looks like it is. Playing with it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I think you need **`Dynamic PIVOT and Group By`**
**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8ea6e/5)**

```
declare @cols varchar(max)
declare @query varchar(max)
DECLARE @selective nvarchar(max)

SELECT @selective =
  STUFF((SELECT ',MAX(' + QUOTENAME(t.col2) +') as ' + QUOTENAME(t.col2)  AS ColName    
         from (
         select distinct  col2                            
         FROM yourtable
         )  t                     
         FOR XML PATH( ''), TYPE).value ('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(t.col2)  AS ColName   
         from (
         select distinct  col2                            
         FROM yourtable
         )  t                 
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

set @query = ' ;with CTE_PivotTable
               as
               (
               select ID, Col1, ' + @cols + 
             ' from 
                    ( select ID, Col1, Col2, Col3 
                      from yourtable
                    ) t
                    pivot
                       (
                          max(col3) for col2 in ('+@Cols+')
                        ) as P
                )
                select Col1, ' + @selective + 
                'from CTE_PivotTable
                 group by Col1'

exec(@query)
```

**OUTPUT RESULT**

```
COL1 | FIVE  |  FOUR  |  ONE  |  SIX  |  THREE  | TWO
-----------------------------------------------------
a    | 500   |  400   |  100  | (null)|  300    | 200 
b    | (null)|  900   |  1000 | 1200  |  1100   | 700 
c    |(null) |  1600  |  2000 | 1700  |  1800   |1900
```

Comment: Why people down vote wihtout leaving a reason? What is wrong? Let me know, I would appreciate to learn.